# Email List Management

Tags: email, forms, best-practice, integration

We are working to find the best way to handle our contacts for our newsletter.

1. Is there any way to integrate Ninja Forms with CiviCRM so that they can send information with each other?
2. Does CiviCRM have a native email sign-up form that we can use that would also work?
3. What are the CiviCRM best practices for email list management, including sign-up forms?  We are trying to find a way to have contacts added to Civi and the appropriate groups to receive our newsletter in an automated way if possible.  If that's not possible, how are others handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your Groups to be 'public' then they can appear at a link like this

https://civicrm.org/civicrm/mailing/subscribe

You can also use a Profile with a Custom Field, and then build a Smart Group based on that field, and use that for your Mailing List

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE! To answer your first question, Ninja forms are developing an integration with CiviCRM. They took over Caldera forms and are migrating it to Ninja forms and this is part of that process. Its not quite finished yet. See https://calderaforms.com/2021/12/2-important-announcements-for-caldera-forms

On the wider question there are quite a lot of ways of doing the sign-up for the newsletter and that depends on how you want to identify who gets it, but one simple way is a group and use a profile to allow people to join the group. I think this also allows unscribing from the group from a link in the email but I haven't tried this. Worth looking at the mailing documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving many answers because there are *many* ways to handle newsletter signup, and the "correct" answer depends mainly on you.

- Do you have just one "newsletter" group?  The [Profiles documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/ca/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#managing-email-lists) discusses using profiles for that purpose.  Make sure to check out the double opt-in options available in **Administer » CiviMail » CiviMail Component Options**.
- You can also use Profiles with multiple groups by adding the "Groups" field and marking your public groups as such (per Pete's answer).
- Do you want to embed the signup page into another page?  On WordPress you would need to use Caldera Forms, [WPForms](https://civicrm.org/extensions/wpforms-civicrm) (some assembly required), or (soon) Ninja Forms.

These are just the simplest approaches.  You might also use CiviRules, and you may also have to account for GDPR and/or CCPA.  Rest assured that many organizations are using CiviCRM to manage their newsletters.